# Edited: I'm trying to call from a dict while using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays

When I try to call from a dict by using an integer for example:

```
dict = {
  'red' : 'purple',
  'blue' : 'orange',
  'green' : 'cyan'
}
item = dict[0]
```

(In this example I would want the result to be 'purple')
It gives me an error, does anyone have a fix for this

I tried doing lots of different things for example a few of these:

```
item = dict[(.)]
item = dict(.)
item = dict{.}
item = dict{(.)}
```

Does anyone have a way that actually works having been informed you can't use indexing

Comment: That is not a list, it's a dict, and dicts are not indexable by position.  The first dict value can be retrieved with `next(iter(d.values()))`

Comment: that is not a list, but a dictionary. Also, using list as variable name is not a good idea, list is used by python already

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your "list" is a dictionary, which cannot be indexed by position. If you want to index by position, convert to list:

```
item = list(lst.values())[0]
```

Or, if the process is to be repeated:

```
actual_lst = list(lst.values())
item = actual_lst[0]
```

Output: `'purple'`

Answer (score 0):

dictionaries in python are not ordered, so they don't have indices like lists do. instead, you should access dictionary values using keys

```
item = my_dict['red']
print(item)
```

Comment: Ducts are ordered, but they are not indexable by position

Comment: My python info may be out of date. Do you know after which version it was ordered? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @FarukKaraca Python 3.6+

Comment: thank youu @Jab